# Power BI - how to format Numeric value from One Column but show different format on Row level

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I would like to ask how to format each row individually but those data comes from same column

for example

```
Col1   Measure
 A      1.01
 B      0.02
 C      2.11111
```

so that when i have a table chart, it want it to show

```
Col1   Measure
A        1        (wholeNumber)
B        2%       (Percentage)
C        2.11     (two decimals)
```

Thanks guys

Comment: Why do you have a single measure returning different types of values instead of creating separate measures? (There are certainly valid reasons to do this, but I'd like to know yours.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one format associated with a column or measure.

If you have a measure that needs to return different formats, your only option is to convert them all to text type and specify how to display the format using `FORMAT()`.

For example, a measure could look like this:

```
Measure = SWITCH(VALUES(Table1[Col1]),
              "A", FORMAT(COUNTROWS(Table1), "0"),
              "B", FORMAT(SUM(Table1[Value])/[TotalValue], "0%"),
              "C", FORMAT(SUM(Table1[Value]), "Standard")
          )
```

These should look OK in a table, but remember that they are text.